# How to protect a question?

Tags: discussion

Is there a reputation cap we have to reach before [this](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/2337/how-did-thor-and-banner-know-where-to-go) feature unlocks for us? or is it something which is exclusive to the Mods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be done by normal users, but you need [3,500 reputation](https://movies.stackexchange.com/privileges/protect-questions) (so you're almost there ;)). But keep in mind that those high-level mod-like facilities should be used with extreme care and responsibility.

Also remember that the beta status of this site lowers the reputation limits for all privileges. Once the site is promoted to a full SE site, you will need the full [15,000](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/protect-questions) again.

Comment: cool. I saw posts being protected wondered how it was done

Comment: @Dredd - yes, protecting questions is fairly rare - usually something that is suddenly very popular and gets a load of 'answers' by people making comments.

Comment: I didn't got a chance to use this power because we have very less question which have large number of answers